# BadRequestException when calling the ExecuteStatement operation on Aurora Serverless db

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk, aws-aurora-serverless

I have a lambda function that retrieves records from AWS Aurora Serverless db. Now I thought of adding api gateway to trigger the lambda function but I get this error.

```
[ERROR] BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: 
Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.x.xx.xxx' (using password: YES); Error code: 1045; SQLState: 28000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 11, in handler
    sql="SELECT * FROM ecomdev.Customer;"
```

What is causing BadRequestException when calling the ExecuteStatement operation on Aurora Serverless db. I have used AWS CDK to create the stacks.
i have deployed the db in isolated subnet of VPC and created a lambda role to access the db along with role policies to access the db secret from secretmanager.

Lambda is not inside the vpc. I tested the lambda code and it gets the records perfectly.
But when I add an api gateway with Lambda rest api to trigger the lambda function I get above error.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by destroying the stack and redeploying it.